# Programming Multiple .FindNext in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I am relatively inexperienced in VBA but can usually get simple tasks completed.  I am currently having an issue with the .Find function.  I know excel does not have the ability to do two .finds, but I am having problems coding a loop for the second find.  The code I have so far is here:

```
Dim j As Integer

Dim Total As Integer
Total = Application.CountIf(Sheets("Output").Range("A:A"), "*Structure*")

Dim class As String
class = "CLASS ="

Dim str As String
str = "Structure" 

With Sheets("output")
Set rng1 = .Range("A:A").Find(str, lookat:=xlPart)
    row1 = rng1.Row
Set rng2 = .Range("A:A").FindNext(rng1)
    row2 = rng2.Row

            For j = 6 To Total + 5
                    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Sheets("output").Range("A" & row1 & ":A" & row2), "*" & class & "*") > 0 Then
                        Set rng3 = .Range("A" & row1 & ":A" & row2).Find(class, lookat:=xlPart)
                        Sheets("sheet2").Cells(7, j).Value = Mid(rng3, 9, 3)         
                    Else
                        Sheets("sheet2").Cells(7, j).Value = ""
                    End If
                        row1 = row2
                        Set rng2 = .Range("A:A").FindNext(rng2)
                        row2 = rng2.Row
            Next j
End With
```

I have the code searching for the word "Structure" in order to create a Range for the second .Find and then fill out a table on a different worksheet.  I know the issue is with the multiple .Find but could not find any help that I could fully understand.

Comment: what is the error you are receiving? why is there an asterisk on either end of structure?

Comment: The cell the includes "structure" may have text on either side of it.  I'm not getting an error, but after the program finds rng3, that becomes the new search item.  So rng2 does not search for "Structure" anymore, and the table fails to skip cells that don't have rng3.

Answer (score 1):

You may find it easier to abstract out the "find all matches" part into a separate function.  That will simplify your logic, and make the real task easier to manage.

Note: this doesn't search for "*CLASS =*" after the last "*structure*" cell - it's not clear if you need to do that.

```
Sub Tester()

    Dim found As Collection, i As Long, f As Range, v

    With ActiveSheet

        'start by finding all of the "structure" cells...
        Set found = FindAll(.Range("A:A"), "*Structure*")

        'then loop over them...
        For i = 1 To found.Count - 1

            v = ""
            Set f = .Range("A" & found(i).Row & ":A" & _
                                 found(i + 1).Row).Find("*CLASS =*")

            If Not f Is Nothing Then v = Mid(f, 9, 3)
            Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(7, 5 + i).Value = v

        Next i

    End With

End Sub
```

The `FindAll` function:

```
Public Function FindAll(rng As Range, val As String) As Collection
    Dim rv As New Collection, f As Range
    Dim addr As String

    Set f = rng.Find(what:=val, after:=rng.Cells(rng.Cells.Count), _
        LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
        SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)
    If Not f Is Nothing Then addr = f.Address()

    Do Until f Is Nothing
        rv.Add f
        Set f = rng.FindNext(after:=f)
        If f.Address() = addr Then Exit Do
    Loop

    Set FindAll = rv
End Function
```

Comment: That worked great! Thank you so much.  I guess I need to do a few more tutorials!  There would be one more "*Class = *" after the last "structure" cell but at least this gets me passed one more hurdle.