# VBA-Excel CTRL Find

Tags: vba, excel

I am currently trying to find a certain word within an excel spreadsheet, copy the cell on the right and then paste it a further 3 cells to the right and 3 cells down, before dragging this down.

I have compiled the following which does the job.

```
Cells.Find(What:="N/C:", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt _
    :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
    False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
    Selection.Offset(0, 1).Select
Selection.Copy

Selection.Offset(3, 3).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select

Selection.FillDown
```

**My question is:**
How can I extend this code so it searches for all "N/C:" and does the above

Feel free to provide updates to my initial code if it can be improved

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45020237/programming-multiple-findnext-in-vba/45020602#45020602

Comment: Hi Tim, this is going to sound really dumb but I can't seem to fully understand the code in the link you said - would it be possible to provide an overview of what is happening??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lightly tested:

```
Sub Tester()

    Dim col As Collection, c, sht As Worksheet

    Set sht = ActiveSheet

    Set col = FindAll(sht.UsedRange, "N/C:")
    Debug.Print "Found " & col.Count & " matches"

    For Each c In col
        c.Copy c.Offset(3, 3)
        sht.Range(c.Offset(3, 3), c.Offset(3, 3).End(xlDown)).FillDown
    Next c


End Sub


Public Function FindAll(rng As Range, val As String) As Collection
    Dim rv As New Collection, f As Range
    Dim addr As String

    Set f = rng.Find(what:=val, after:=rng.Cells(rng.Cells.Count), _
        LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
        SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)

    If Not f Is Nothing Then addr = f.Address()

    Do Until f Is Nothing
        rv.Add f
        Set f = rng.FindNext(after:=f)
        If f.Address() = addr Then Exit Do
    Loop

    Set FindAll = rv
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that there is no built-in way to return a range with all the find results (i.e. find all) in one go. You have to find the first result (the code you already have) and then use findNext within a while loop, exiting only when the next result until it refers to the same cell as the first result.

There is a good explanation/implementation at http://www.cpearson.com/excel/findall.aspx

Comment: Thank you for this link! it is extremely helpful - i'm still struggling to get my while loop correct so any further help will be appreciated