# Counting the total number of search results found with Excel's Find Method

Tags: excel, vba

Is it possible to return the total number of matches found using Excel's find method? If so, how would that look or how would I go about counting the total number of search results?

Here's what I have so far that i'd like to build on:

```
Private Sub btnSearch_Click()

    With Sheet1
        Set foundCell = .Cells.Find(What:="B-32", After:=.Cells(1, 1), _
        LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
        SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
    End With

    If Not foundCell Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox ("""Bingo"" found in row " & foundCell.Row)
            UserForm1.location.Text = Cells(foundCell.Row, 3).Value
            UserForm1.office.Value = Cells(foundCell.Row, 2).Value
            UserForm1.floor.Value = Cells(foundCell.Row, 1).Value
            UserForm1.status.Value = Cells(foundCell.Row, 4).Value
            UserForm1.telephone.Value = Cells(foundCell.Row, 5).Value
            UserForm1.mobile.Value = Cells(foundCell.Row, 6).Value
            UserForm1.owner.Value = Cells(foundCell.Row, 7).Value
            UserForm1.notes.Value = Cells(foundCell.Row, 8).Value
    Else
            MsgBox ("Bingo not found")
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45020237/programming-multiple-findnext-in-vba/45020602#45020602

Comment: This might help  <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19504858/find-all-matches-in-workbook-using-excel-vba>

Comment: Assuming that handler is in the form's code-behind, don't refer to state that's in the form's default instance from that form's code-behind, it will bite you sooner or later. Use `Me` instead of `UserForm1`, to refer to *whichever instance of the form has the state*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was thinking:

```
Option Explicit

'Global Variables
Dim foundCell


Private Sub btnSearch_Click()

Dim Str
Dim FirstAddr As String

Str = "B-32"


    With Sheet1
        Set foundCell = .Cells.Find(What:=Str, After:=.Cells(1, 1), _
                        LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
    End With


    If Not foundCell Is Nothing Then

        MsgBox ("""Bingo"" found in row " & foundCell.Row)

        UserForm1.location.Text = Cells(foundCell.Row, 3).Value
        UserForm1.office.Value = Cells(foundCell.Row, 2).Value
        UserForm1.floor.Value = Cells(foundCell.Row, 1).Value
        UserForm1.status.Value = Cells(foundCell.Row, 4).Value
        UserForm1.telephone.Value = Cells(foundCell.Row, 5).Value
        UserForm1.mobile.Value = Cells(foundCell.Row, 6).Value
        UserForm1.owner.Value = Cells(foundCell.Row, 7).Value
        UserForm1.notes.Value = Cells(foundCell.Row, 8).Value

        FirstAddr = foundCell.Address

    Else
            MsgBox ("Bingo not found")
    End If

    Dim i As Integer

    Do Until foundCell Is Nothing

        Set foundCell = Sheet1.Cells.FindNext(After:=foundCell)

        i = i + 1

        If foundCell.Address = FirstAddr Then Exit Do
    Loop

    MsgBox (i)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

> Counting the total number of search

you could use `CountIF()`

also, always explicitly qualify range references up to wanted worksheet

finally, mind Mathieu Guindon's piece of advice

as follows:

```
With Sheet1
    Set foundCell = .Cells.Find(What:="B-32", After:=.Cells(1, 1), _
    LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
    SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

    If Not foundCell Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox ("""Bingo"" found " & WorksheetFunction.CountIf(.Cells, "*B-32*") & " times")

        MsgBox ("first ""Bingo"" found in row " & foundCell.Row)

        Me.Location.Text = .Cells(foundCell.Row, 3).Value
        Me.Office.Value = .Cells(foundCell.Row, 2).Value
        Me.Floor.Value = .Cells(foundCell.Row, 1).Value
        Me.Status.Value = .Cells(foundCell.Row, 4).Value
        Me.telephone.Value = .Cells(foundCell.Row, 5).Value
        Me.mobile.Value = .Cells(foundCell.Row, 6).Value
        Me.owner.Value = .Cells(foundCell.Row, 7).Value
        Me.Notes.Value = .Cells(foundCell.Row, 8).Value
    Else
        MsgBox ("Bingo not found")
    End If
End With
```